# Is there a good resource for beautiful HTML forms?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, forms

I am working in rails, and a looking for some resources to design visually pleasing HTML forms. I can write the CSS, so even examples would be great.

Any recommendations?

Comment: If you can write the CSS, what's stopping you just coming up with a nice design then implementing it?

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com - always good for general UX guidance and I know they have forms-specific articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many resources out there, you can just google for well looking forms or something like this.

There are also javascript libraries which makes customized selects/checkboxes etc -for example a project called [uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) - check it out, you might like it. It provides you tools to customize it.

Comment: They are very clean - and much better than the default Rails forms. It's a big improvement with minimal work. And cross-platform and cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Gravity Forms for WordPress then you never need to hand code the html and it inserts unique id's and matching classes in the HTML.  This means the sky is the limit when it comes to styling your form.

If you are not using WordPress, here is a nice tutorial for [designing form layouts](http://www.noupe.com/php/beautiful-forms.html).